# Как разбить сообщение на 2 части циклом python

Tags: python, циклы

Есть функция которая собирает 50 пользователей в формате "1. [Ник]: [кол-во сообщений]" с базы данных в одно сообщение:

```
def global_top(self, chatid):
   sql.execute("SELECT userid, nick, SUM(messages) FROM users GROUP BY userid ORDER BY SUM(messages) DESC")
   asd = sql.fetchmany(50)

   full_message = "TOP-50: \n"

   for i, tup in enumerate(asd, 1):
        full_message += f'{i}. {tup[1]}: {tup[2]}\n'
   subclient.send_message(chatId=chatid, message=full_message)
```

Нужно разбить топ-50 на 2 сообщения по 25 мест не нарушая нумерацию.

Comment: Собирать эти строки в список, потом брать срезы и вписывать в сообщение, либо сделать ```split('\n') ``` и брать оттуда срезы

Comment: Можно пример пожалуйста как это можно сделать в моем случае? приму ваш ответ

Comment: @Nobody Зачем словарь, можно же просто в список. Потом через срезы разбить на 2, и объединять через `'\n'.join(...)`.

Comment: @Jazzis не то слово написал) список имел в виду, исправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
first25 = [f'{i}. {tup[1]}: {tup[2]}' for i, tup in enumerate(asd[:25], 1)]
others = [f'{i}. {tup[1]}: {tup[2]}' for i, tup in enumerate(asd[25:], 1)]

f25_msg = '\n'.join(first25)
oth_msg = '\n'.join(others)
```

Не самый элегантный способ из-за дублирования кода, но он должен сработать

Обратите внимание, что в 1 и 2 строке отличаются индексы срезов списка `asd`